# Cordless router in router table

Tags: router, router-table

Are cordless trim routers compatible with any router tables?

Comment: That link will be dead in an internet moment, pretty much making this Question moot for future visitors. In general, model specific questions pretty much end up as "shopping" questions, which are off-topic here. This is the sort of ephemeral question more suited for a web search or a forum that is aimed at information that goes out of date fast (e.g., Reddit). Maybe see the [tour] to get a feel for what SE sites are all about.

Comment: That all being said, the answer to your question is probably "not officially". Plam routers don't often have table attachments. But a web search will confirm this.

Comment: Any router is compatible with router-table use if you make the 'table' yourself. I say 'table' because you don't have to make a formal table, full-size, mini or whatever — the simplest mounting for a router is just screwing it to the underside of a sheet of ply or chipboard, that you then clamp to the edge of a bench. That's it, literally. This is all some pros use, including the author of the iconic **Router Handbook** which was the bible on the subject for many years.

Answer (score 1):

Probably. Trim router tables are manufactured and one or more would most likely fit this model. You could also fabricate a baseplate/mounting plate to make this trim router fit other, standard router tables if you're so inclined.

The real question is whether or not this router could handle the demands placed upon it when mounted to a table. You'll probably be happier with a corded router that has better power specifications and is built to use with a table.